# Can I change the name of a project in codeplex before publishing?

Tags: open-source, version-control, naming, mercurial, codeplex

I started a project repo on codeplex and haven't publicly published it yet. I realized that the name I gave to it is not appropriate and would like to change the name of the project before publicly releasing it (they have a 30 day deadline). The name of the directory that hg clone needs, i.e., `dirname` in `https://hg01.codeplex.com/dirname` is ok, but the project shows up in a different name in codeplex, and that is the name I want to change. Is this possible?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about the usage of some tool, not about software engineering concepts. See: [Where does my tool question go?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7253)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the name in the URL at any time using the field on the "Edit Project Summary & Details" page. This even adds a redirect for you and you can do it after the project has ben published.